# Iframe Switch Button in HTML

Tags: html

How do I make a toggle button that runs an iframe?
[The code i have so far](http://pastebin.com/rTyESFgQ)

This just launches the swf file from the URL, but I want it to launch in an iframe so i can keep it in the website.

Comment: You may post your code here to make the world easier for the readers and people who want to help you

Comment: I can't because the output doesn't show the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
<input type="button" value="Load" onclick="loadPage();"/>
<iframe id="testiframe" width="400" height="300" src="">
<script>
function loadPage() {
     document.getElementById('testiframe').src = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page';
}
</script>
```

Change src in the code, to the site you want to load.
Wee running example: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/6mSuK/2/